# Iframes with textbox

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

What's wrong with my code? Only the second iframe works while the first box doesn't.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="url-setter">
  <input type="text" value='' name="url" id="url" />
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<iframe id="the-frame" width="540" height="480"></iframe>
<iframe id="the-frame1" width="540" height="480"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter'),
      url = document.getElementById('url'),
      the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame');
    url_setter.onsubmit = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      the_iframe.src = url.value;
    };
  }());
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter'),
      url = document.getElementById('url'),
      the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame1');
    url_setter.onsubmit = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      the_iframe.src = url.value;
    };
  }());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, don't assign the `onsubmit` twice, second, you need to get the `url` elements value when `onsubmit` fires, or else there isn't any value.

Stack snippet

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="url-setter">
  <input type="text" value='' name="url" id="url" />
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<iframe id="the-frame" width="540" height="480"></iframe>
<iframe id="the-frame1" width="540" height="480"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    "use strict";
    var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter'),
      the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame'),
      the_iframe1 = document.getElementById('the-frame1');

    url_setter.onsubmit = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var url = document.getElementById('url');
      the_iframe.src = url.value;
      the_iframe1.src = url.value;
    };
  }());
</script>
```